# Crafting Glitch?

Tags: the-witcher-2

So I went to try and craft myself a weapon called a Jagged Blade. I had all the proper materials, and I got Cedric to craft it for me. Or I thought I did. After getting the "crafting completed" heads up I go in my inventory to equip it. What's this? Where is it? It didn't even pop up in my inventory. I figured maybe I'm not looking in the right place, so I look at the tutorial to see maybe I have to pick it up from somewhere. Nope. Should pop up right in my inventory. So here I am, very confused, wanting to have my new weapon. So I decide maybe it was a glitch with Cedric that I didn't know about, and maybe you're not supposed to craft items with him even though it says you can. I gather the components to craft another Jagged Blade. I go to a different craftsmen, this time one around the outside of Flotsam. Get him to craft it. Look in my inventory aaaand not there. What's going on? Why am I not recieving my painfully crafted items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't "selecting" what I wanted to craft and was crafting something else instead. A pretty stupid mistake, and I feel stupid for it, but it happens.